# Coded UI - Next test aborts after the current test timesout

Tags: automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I am running multiple coded ui tests and have the basic structure of [testinitialize] and [testcleanup] methods.
The cleanup method closes the application and I have a finally in the cleanup which reports the test status. This works fine when a test passes or fails.

But when a test timesout, the execution of the cleanup/ finally block of cleanup gets delayed and the [testinitialize] of the next test starts before the current cleanup method completes causing the next test to abort.

How should I be handling the timeout scenario?

Comment: May be you could post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  What language is this?

Comment: Adding a finally block in cleanup method is not really a best practice. I think removing finally block might help you here.
I suggest, maybe you should avoid using the finally block in the cleanup method. And maybe you can report the test status before closing application.

Comment: Can you please share the demo code which includes [testinitialize] and [testcleanup]?